# How to send to the top with AjaxPagingNavigator

Tags: java, wicket, paging

I want to send to the top of the page each time the user clicks on a page in a AjaxPagingNavigator. I can send via a href="#topofpage" which works for a static link, but setting this value in the href ov my extended PagingNavigator (for GUI customization only) does not work.

What would be the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to the links in the `AjaxPagingNavigator` an `AjaxEventBehavior` which would on `click` perform the scroll top:

```
add(new AjaxPagingNavigator("id", pageable){

    @Override
    protected AbstractLink newPagingNavigationLink(String id, IPageable pageable, int pageNumber) {
        AbstractLink link = newPagingNavigationLink(id, pageable, pageNumber); 
        link.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.appendJavaScript("$(\"html\").scrollTop(0);");
            }
        });

        return link;
    }

});
```

Comment: Nice, will try it out right away. This should also allow me to call other Javascript code...

Comment: Well, at the end it was more complex, I had to override newPagingNavigationIncrementLink and newNavigation, but your idea was the clue of what I needed to do... Also, the AjaxBehavior didn't quite work, but I used a AttributeAppender to add the scroll to the link and it's doing the job. Thank you very much for your help...